# SSH connect to periphery server directly through a central landing server

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I have a situation where I can connect to server A (the 'landing server') and server A can connect to server B (the 'periphery server'). I do not have any direct access to server B.

Currently, I ssh to A and then ssh from there to B. I have created an ssh config for this as such:

```
Host B
    Hostname <A-hostname>
    User <A-user>
    RequestTTY yes
    RemoteCommand ssh <B-user>@<B-hostname>
```

This works when working interactively but it does not work correctly with scp etc. Running `ssh -J A B` results in `B: Permission denied (publickey)`. I cannot add my public key to B.

How can I make this work?

**EDIT**: Basically, what I want to achieve is: use my private key to create connection to A and then use A's private key to create connection to B, all in a way that, ideally, scp etc can correctly use.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work with scp etc. because your RemoteCommand does not preserve the *original* command that was sent to "B", which is how the server-side scp process is started.

If the server A is running OpenSSH, your RemoteCommand needs to run a script that would pass the contents of `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` to the `ssh B` command – as well as dynamically adding either `-t` or `-T` depending on whether the script itself has a tty or not.

(Note that always requesting a tty might cause data corruption during non-interactive transfers; scp/sftp assume a clean channel and aren't expecting the special handling done by the TTY layer for certain bytes. If scp uses `ssh -T` to explicitly disable tty request again, that should be fine – as long as the RemoteCommand carries this over to the next connection.)

Comment: Yes exactly. How can I define the B host so that scp etc just work? -J (and the corresponding ProxyJump directive) are not working.

Comment: By doing what's suggested in the 2nd paragraph.